# Laravel - Method paginate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to paginate the orders from the controller like

```
 $orders = Order::openorders()->paginate(15);
```

and in the model I have this:

```
public static function stats()
{
    return Stats::where(\DB::raw('SUBSTRING(statistics, 5, 5)'), '!=','D')->where('statistics', 'NOT LIKE', '%F%')->where('statistics', 'NOT LIKE', '%X%')->get()->sortByDesc('date');
}
```

and it is showing this message:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException 
Method paginate does not exist.
```

Comment: i want to sort by date first then paginate

Comment: You are calling paginate() on a collection when the method is defined in the query build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method chaining refers to `this` you cannot chain static and public method like this But you can take advantage of [scopes()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes).

change the name of your method like this.

```
public  function scopeOpenorders($query)
{
    return $query->where(\DB::raw('SUBSTRING(cu_stat, 1, 1)'), '!=','C')
         ->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%D%')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%X%')
         ->orderBy('cu_date','DESC');
}
```

You can learn more about scopes here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

Hope this helps.

Comment: the **sort** method not exist in query builder, use **orderBy()**

Comment: I like the use of a scope

Comment: also **openordersScope** change to **scopeOpenorders**

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `paginate` method after `get` results. Therefore error occurred,

```
    public static function openorders() {
           return Order::where(\DB::raw('SUBSTRING(cu_stat, 1, 1)'), '!=','C')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%D%')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%X%')->orderBy('cu_date', 'desc');
     }
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

instead of sortByDesc, I used

```
orderBy('cu_date', 'desc')->paginate(15)
```

in the Model and it worked

Model:

```
return Order::where(\DB::raw('SUBSTRING(cu_stat, 1, 1)'), '!=','C')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%D%')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%X%')->orderBy('cu_date', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

and Controller:

```
$orders = Order::openorders();
```

Answer (score 0):

model :

```
public static function openorders($sort='cu_date',$sort_type='asc',$count=10)
{
    return Order::where(\DB::raw('SUBSTRING(cu_stat, 1, 1)'), '!=','C')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%D%')->where('cu_stat', 'NOT LIKE', '%X%')->orderBy($sort, $sort_type)->paginate($count);
}
```

controller :

```
$orders=Order::openorders('cu_date','asc',1);
```